# Is there a way to suppress the "catch branch identical" warning? Unable to use multi catch in this instance

Tags: java, android, suppress-warnings

Working on an android application with API 17 and currently needing to do some reflection to complete a task. The ReflectiveOperationException is only available for use from API 19 and up, however this is fine since I can simply catch each exception individually.

The problem is when I do, I get a warning saying the catch branches are identical and can be written using a multi-catch (or use Exception which I'd like to avoid). But when I write the catches as a multi-catch, I get the error saying I can't use the ReflectiveOperationException class due to not being API 19.

Simply put I'd like to just suppress the warning but wasn't able to find anything that matches besides just doing @SuppressWarning("all")

For context, here are the  warnings/errors:

```
// Error: "Multi-catch with these reflection exceptions requires API level 19 (current min is 15) 
// because they get compiled to the common but new super type ReflectiveOperationException.
// As a workaround either create individual catch statements, or catch Exception."
try {
    return someMethodThatThrowsExceptions();
} catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
}

// Warning: 'catch' branch identical to 'InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException' branch"
try {
    return someMethodThatThrowsExceptions();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
}
```

Edit: added all the catches I was dealing with, originally only had two

Comment: Weird catch-22.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`@SuppressWarnings("TryWithIdenticalCatches")` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For suppressing certain warnings I have a utility function like this:

```
public static <T> T get( T value )
{
    return value;
}
```

So, you can feed `e` to this `get()` function before throwing it, thus making the two `catch` clauses non-equal.

Comment: I see, as a workaround I can get that it'll make two expcetions non-equal, but what happens when it's more than two? I'll edit my post since I'm actually dealing with more than two exceptions (but all subclasses of the RelectiveOperationException)

Comment: Well, the compiler does not know whether `get()` has any side-effects, so it may just shut up if you use `get()`, regardless of the branches being identical.  If it doesn't, then you can do `get(get(e))`, or you can add a `get( N );` with a different N in each `catch` statement.